# Compiling Yacc code

Tags: yacc

Below is my yacc code to parse C source code. I am a little new to this and this is an already existing code.

```
{

%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include "Expression.c"

%}


%token Identifier
%token Number
%token '=' '+' '-' '*' '/' ',' ';' '(' ')' '{' '}' '[' ']' '<' '>'
%token INT
%token CHAR
%token FLOAT
%token LONG
%token DOUBLE
%token RETURN
%token IF
%token ELSE
%token EQ       /* == */
%token BADTOKEN

%%

program
 : function 
     { $$ = $1; }
 | program function 
    { $$ = binaryNode("",$1,$2);}
 | error '}'    

function: 
 typename Identifier '(' formal.arguments ')' function.body
    { $$ = attachAllChildren($2,$1,$4,$6); }

typename
 : INT 
    { $$ = leafNode("INT");}
 | CHAR 
    { $$ = leafNode("CHAR"); }
 | DOUBLE 
    { $$ = leafNode("DOUBLE"); }
 | LONG 
    { $$ = leafNode("LONG"); }
 | FLOAT
    { $$ = leafNode("FLOAT"); }

formal.arguments
 :  /* empty */
    { $$ = NULL; }
 | formal.argument.list
    { $$ = $1; }

formal.argument.list
 : formal.argument
    { $$ = $1; }
 | formal.argument.list ',' formal.argument
    { $$ = binaryNode(",", $1, $3); }

formal.argument
 : typename Identifier
    { $$ = attachChild($2, $1); }

function.body
 : '{' '}'
    { $$ = NULL; }
 | '{' statements '}'
    { $$ = $2; }

statements
 : statement
    { $$ = $1; }
 | statements statement
    { $$ = attachChild($1,$2);}

statement
 : declaration
    { $$ = $1; }
 | RETURN expression ';'        /* return statement */
    { $$ = unaryNode("RETURN", $2); }
 | if.statement
    { $$ =$1; }
 | term '=' expression ';'      /* assignment */
    { $$ = binaryNode("=", $1, $3); }
 | expression ';'
    { $$ = $1; }

 | '{' statements '}'
    { $$ = $2; }

 | ';'              /* null statement */
    { $$ = NULL; }

declaration
 : typename Identifier ';'
    { $$ = attachChild($2,$1); }

 | typename Identifier '[' Number ']' ';'   /* array */
    { $$ = attachSiblings($2, $1, $4); }

if.statement
 : IF '(' expression ')' statement
    { $$ = ternaryNode("IF",$3,$5, NULL); }

 | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
    { $$ = ternaryNode("IF", $3, $5, $7); }

expression
 : additive.expression
    { $$ = $1; }
 | expression EQ additive.expression
    { $$ = binaryNode("=",$1, $3); }
 | expression '>' additive.expression
    { $$ = binaryNode(">", $1, $3); }
 | expression '<' additive.expression
    { $$ = binaryNode("<", $1, $3); }

additive.expression
 : term
    { $$ = $1; }
 | additive.expression '+' term
    { $$ = binaryNode("+", $1, $3);}
 | additive.expression '-' term
    { $$ = binaryNode("-", $1, $3);}

term
 : Identifier
    { $$ = leafNode($1);}
 | Number
    { $$ = leafNode($1);}
 | Identifier '(' opt.actual.arguments ')'  /* function call */
    { $$ = attachChild($1,$3);}
 | Identifier '[' expression ']'        /* array access */
    { $$ = attachChild($1,$3); }
 | '(' expression ')'
    { $$ = $2;}


 opt.actual.arguments
  : /* empty */
    { $$ = NULL;}
  | actual.arguments
    { $$=$1; }


 actual.arguments
   : expression
    { $$ = $1; }

   | actual.arguments ',' expression
    { $$ = binaryNode(",",$1, $3); }

 %%

 yyerror(msg)
 char* msg;
 {
   #if !defined(YYBISON)
   extern int yynerrs;

   ++yynerrs;
   #endif
   fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n",msg);
  }             

 main()
 {
    extern int yynerrs;
    yyparse();
    fprintf(stderr, "%d errors.\n", yynerrs);
    return 0;
  }
 }
```

On compiling the above code , I get a warning that there is 1 shift/reduce conflict in the code. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-v` option to yacc, which will produce a `y.output` file telling you where the conflict is and how its is triggered.  Note that a conflict is NOT an error -- you still get a valid parser from yacc -- but that parser may not recognize exactly the language defined by your grammar.

In your case, you get something like:

```
State 81 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
        :
State 81

   28 if.statement: IF '(' expression ')' statement .
   29             | IF '(' expression ')' statement . ELSE statement

    ELSE  shift, and go to state 83

    ELSE      [reduce using rule 28 (if.statement)]
    $default  reduce using rule 28 (if.statement)
```

which tells you that you have the classic [dangling else ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), so you can probably just ignore the conflict, as the generated parser will resolve the ambiguity by binding the else to the closest if, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Yes absolutely , but what kind of tokens should be generated by my lexer (I primarily want only arithmetic operations and their respective operators to be generated? Also can I just the the remove the node assignment statements as far as the abstract syntax tree in the above parser is concerned?

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty:  I'm not sure I understand your followup question.  Your lexer needs to generate the tokens used by your parser.  The assignment statements (in the actions) of your .y file build an AST.  If you don't want/need an AST then you can get rid of them -- actions have no effect on the language parsed (unless they feed back info to the lexer), they are just run as rules are reduced by the parser.